# How can I make sure pushPayload doesn't happen while affected records are inFlight?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am experimenting with turning a more traditional ember-data based app into a real-time app that uses websockets to keep multiple instances in sync.

My first attempt involves sending any updated record back to all open sessions that have accessed the record so that they all can have the latest copy. This includes the session that initiated the change. This means that after I call `record.save()` in the client, I get back the updated copy both from the REST API and the websocket. The client-end of the websocket simply calls `store.pushPayload(data)` to update the store.

This causes problems because the record might be `inFlight` at the time, and I get the error:

```
Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on [...] while in state root.deleted.inFlight.
```

I have several ideas:

1. Somehow prevent the client from receiving its own records back and only send them to other websocket connections.
2. Somehow synchronize access to the store so that when I call `pushPayload` the affected records are not in-flight.

Both of these seem rather complicated and I was hoping there's an established means of keeping multiple Ember apps up-to-date.

Comment: why you don't use existing socket-adapters?

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk, do you have a recommendation? I would prefer to not convert my whole app at this point. Plus I'm not sure how it solves the race-condition problem? What happens when two clients update the same record at the same time and one receives an update from the other while it's own copy of that record is inFlight?

Comment: we use https://github.com/collectrium/ember-data-socketio-adapter